# Combine two KendoUI Jquery scripts

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'd like to combine these two scripts. But can't get it working. I'm really struggling with the jquery part.

This is the script I'm using:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/upload/how-to/select-additional-metadata

And I'd like to add the jQuery part to that script to get the image preview working:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/upload/how-to/add-image-preview

```
        <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#files").kendoUpload({
      async: {
        saveUrl: "save",
        removeUrl: "remove",
        autoUpload: false
      },
      multiple: false,
      select: function(e) {
        var fileInfo = e.files[0];
        var wrapper = this.wrapper;

        setTimeout(function(){
          addPreview(fileInfo, wrapper);
        });
      }
    });
  });

  Combine these two--------------------------------------------------------

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#files").kendoUpload({
                    multiple: true,
                    async: {
                        saveUrl: "save",
                        removeUrl: "remove",
                        autoUpload: false
                    },
                    template: kendo.template($('#fileTemplate').html()),
                    select: onSelect,
                      upload: onUpload
                });
            });
```

Would be great if somebody with knowledge could help me out! :-)

Thank you very much!

Comment: you have multiple set to false and true, i don't believe you can have both in one script

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have multiple files uploaded with preview then do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#files").kendoUpload({
                        multiple: true,
                        async: {
                            saveUrl: "save",
                            removeUrl: "remove",
                            autoUpload: false
                        },
                        select: onSelect,
                          upload: onUpload
                    });
                });

                function onSelect(e){
                  var upload = this;
                  var files = e.files;

                  var fileInfo = e.files[0];
                  var wrapper = this.wrapper;



                  setTimeout(function(e){
                    addPreview(fileInfo, wrapper);
                  });
                }

              function onUpload(e){
                var upload = this;
                var dropdown = upload.wrapper.find(".k-file[data-uid='" + e.files[0].uid +"'] select").data("kendoDropDownList");

                e.data = {
                    uploader: dropdown.value()
                };
              }

              function addPreview(file, wrapper) {
                var raw = file.rawFile;
                var reader  = new FileReader();

                if (raw) {
                  reader.onloadend = function () {
                    var preview = $("<img class='image-preview'>").attr("src", this.result);

                    wrapper.find(".k-file[data-uid='" + file.uid + "'] .k-file-extension-wrapper")
                      .replaceWith(preview);
                  };

                  reader.readAsDataURL(raw);
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Damn you're a genius. The preview is working but the 'upload' script doesn't work anymore for some reason. The upload button stopped working.